# C#-Arduino Communication Mismatch?

Tags: c#, arduino

I'm trying to write a program in C# to communicate with my Arduino UNO from my computer via a serial connection. At the moment I'm just writing a simple application that establishes contact with the Arduino, and then with several controls to control each pin on the arduino; either read a value from it or write a value to it.

I've managed to establish contact with the Arduino and to set pin-values, but it doesn't always want to obey my commands. I set up a few check boxes, and when I check a box, an LED should turn on, and off when I un-check it. The problem is that sometimes the LED's just stay on or off and I have to click the box a few times before it responds again, or reset my circuit...

I was trying to do some fault-finding, but couldn't get to the root of the problem: is it my app or is it the Arduino code?

Here are the relevant pieces of my code:

```
private void sendValue(int RW, int _Pin, int Val) //send from my app to serial port
{
    if (CommPort.IsOpen)
    {
        CommPort.WriteLine(RW.ToString() + "," + _Pin.ToString() + ","  + Val.ToString());
    }
}

private void chP9_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //call the sendValue routine
{
    if (chP9.Checked)
    {
            sendValue(1, 9, 255); //('Write', to pin 9, 'On')
    }
    else
    {
        sendValue(1, 9, 0); //('Write', to pin 9, 'Off')
    }
}
```

This is my C# code, it compiles a comma-delimited string to send over the serial port to be read by the Arduino.

Here's the Arduino code:

```
int RW;    //0 to read pin, 1 to write to pin
int PN;    //Pin number to read or write
int Val;   //Value to write to pin

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(38400);
}

void loop() {
  ReadIncoming();
  ProcessIncoming(); 
}

void ReadIncoming()
{
  if(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    RW = Serial.parseInt();
    PN = Serial.parseInt();
    Val = Serial.parseInt();
  }
  while(Serial.available() > 0) //Clear the buffer if any data remains after reading
  {
    Serial.read();
  }
}

void ProcessIncoming()
{
  if(RW == 0)
  {
    pinMode(PN, INPUT);
  }
  else
  {
    pinMode(PN, OUTPUT);
    analogWrite(PN, Val);
  }
}
```

parseInt just takes out the first integer value it finds, stores it and throws away the comma, and does it again and again, but it seems a bit counter-intuitive.

I think my problem lies here:

```
  while(Serial.available() > 0) //Clear the buffer if any data remains after reading
  {
    Serial.read();
  }
```

I think the App is sending data faster than the Arduino code could handle, especially with this loop, but what do I do with excess data?

I don't like to use the parseInt, but it's the only way I could find to read my instructions correctly. How do I send a byte array from C# and read that array into an array in Arduino?

I've pointed out my hypotheses, and explored alternatives but couldn't get any solutions. What suggestions do you guys have for me?

Comment: No need to pass strings around when a few bytes is what you really want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not that clear to me why it works at all.  You ought to consider a smarter way to encode the command.  You need only three bytes:

```
    private void sendValue(int RW, int _Pin, int Val) {
        var cmd = new byte[] { (byte)RW, (byte)_Pin, (byte)Val };
        ComPort.Write(cmd, 0, cmd.Length);
    }
```

Then you just need to read those 3 bytes on the Arduino end:

```
void ReadIncoming() {
    if (Serial.available() >= 3) {
        RW = Serial.read();
        PN = Serial.read();
        Val = Serial.read();
        ProcessIncoming();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Hans, this works like a charm, thanks! This is what I've been looking for before I tried the parseInt. I've done something similar but I wrote: if(Serial.available() > **0**), and that, as I suspected, read the data before all bytes were present so it didn't work at all.